# searching(selecting) any data from LDAP server using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I want to select(search) any kind of data from my LDAP server. 
I have a connection but I don't know how to retrieve any data. 
Can anyone give a tip so that I can see anything such as data?

**Issue:**

When I run the following code, I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource`

**What I tried?**

DataSource has two imports:

- 1) javax.sql
- 2) javax.activation

I changed different import but didn't work.

My another question is " Are those two imports the same? "

**Source code:**

```
public class LDAPJndi {

    //JNDI API를 사용하여 서버와 연결 (Connecting to LDAP server using JNDI)
    public static  DirContext connectJndi() throws NamingException {

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.0.60:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=govmanager");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "GOVmoi!manager");
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); 
        return ctx;
    } 

    public static void lookupJndi() throws NamingException {
        // a method for looking up any data
        DirContext ctx = connectJndi();
        Object o = ctx.lookup("c=kr");
        System.out.println(o);
        //above didn't work, so tried the bottom
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("c=kr"); //c=kr is BaseDN
        System.out.println(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved this problem by using 'SearchControls'  'searchFilter'  'setSearchScope' 'SearchResult'.  Thank you~

Comment: Hi, if you think you got an answer then write it as an answer with a few explanations and accept it, so that your post gains some visibility and people having the same issue can benefit from it.

Comment: @EricLavault   I c. okay. I'll do that~

Comment: are you using any framework ? like f.e. `spring` ?

Comment: @user3529850   I'm using JNDI API (for LDAP connection) no Spring though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like below.  I just added many comments to experiment. They might confuse some people, so you may delete them as you wish. And I think the recommended imports by Eclipse work the same in this case. Hope it helped!

```
public static  DirContext connectJndi() throws NamingException {

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.0.60:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "your id");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "your password");
    //DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); 
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
    return ctx;
} 


public static void lookupJndi() throws NamingException {
    //DirContext ctx = connectJndi();
    LdapContext ctx = (LdapContext) connectJndi();
    SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
    ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);
    //ctls.setReturningAttributes(new String[] {"cn"});
    //String searchFilter=String.format("(cn=%s)", "cn" );
    String searchFilter="(objectClass=*)";
    //String searchFilter="(o=*)";

    NamingEnumeration<javax.naming.directory.SearchResult> results
     = ctx.search("c=kr", searchFilter,ctls);
    while(results.hasMoreElements()){
        javax.naming.directory.SearchResult sr = results.next();
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        //System.out.println(sr);
        System.out.println(attrs);
    }   
} // method
```